# django dumpdata command throws doesnot exist error

Tags: django

I am trying to add some default/fixed values to postgres database and came across fixtures.

My model is like this
app/models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

app/fixtures/category.json

```
[
  {
    "model": "core.category",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "category": "foo"
    }
]
```

However, I am getting the following error when I run `manage.py dumpdata`

```
[CommandError: Unable to serialize database: cursor "_django_curs_139823939079496_sync_1" does not exist
```

Comment: Your server might be out of memory. Also note that `dumpdata` will export data from the database to a JSON file, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have json file already (**serialize**, means that your django models data has been translated already to json format) you just need to to migrate your data into a new database(you say postgres), try to run these few lines of codes NOTE: I used python3 because I am using macbook pro:-

```
python3 manage.py migrate 
    OR
python3 manage.py migrate --run -syncdb
```

Then, enter your django shell and delete all contenttypes:

```
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> c = ContentType.objects.all()
>>> c.delete()
(55, {'auth.Permission': 44, 'contenttypes.ContentType': 11})
>>> exit()
```

python3 manage.py loaddata datadump.json

- After being notified that all contenttypes has been deleted, You need to ensure that those data will be displayed in your templates. Simply by loading them from from your json file as shown above.*

Comment: I don't understand how it relates, OP has problem dumping its data to json, not loading it